# how to search a string value within a specific column in pandas dataframe, and if present, give an output of that row present in the dataframe?

Tags: loops, pandas, search, sklearn-pandas

I wish to search a database that I have in a .pkl file.

I have loaded the .pkl file and stored it in a variable named load_data.

Now, I need to accept a string input using raw input and search for the string in one specific column '`SMILES`' of my dataset.

If the string matches, I need to display the whole row i.e all column values corresponding to that row.

Is that possible and if so, how should I go about it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please show us what you have done so far, add some code and the results. Make sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) that returns all matching rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,3,4],
                      'SMILES': ['a','dd b','f'],
                     'c': [1,2,0]})
print (df)
  SMILES  a  c
0      a  1  1
1   dd b  3  2
2      f  4  0
```

If you need to check a string only:

```
#raw_input for python 2, input for python 3
a = input('Enter String for SMILES columns: ') # f
#Enter String for SMILES columns: f
print (df[df['SMILES'] == a])
  SMILES  a  c
2      f  4  0
```

Or if you need to check a sub string, use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
a = input('Enter String for SMILES columns: ') # b 
print (df[df['SMILES'].str.contains(a)])
#Enter String for SMILES columns: b
  SMILES  a  c
1   dd b  3  2
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! \

Comment: I really need to handle it in the dataframe format. So I would like to search the input query string into the specific SMILES column.

Comment: Sorry I am pressing enter everytime and the comment is posting itself. The 2nd method worked! How can I present the output of this in form of a dataframe?

Comment: I dont understand, because my solution do it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Below code solve my problem. It search **any value** based on regex in single column and will return all rows based on search keyword. Please update regex according your need.

**Search in single column**

```
regex = ".*" + your search keyword + ".*"

df.loc[df['your_col_name'].str.contains(regex, regex=True, case=False)]
```

**search in all columns**

```
df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains(regex, regex=True, case=False).any(), axis=1)]
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html